# Laravel API can't connect to db

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm trying to build an restful API.

When I make a call to one of my endpoints, I get following error message:

> SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO) (SQL: select * from `users`)

The wierd thing is why this error is showing up when I try to access the endpoint, but when I use `db:seed`, the database is populated with dummy-data and I can use migrations also to create the tables.

The user that is connecting to the db has full privileges.

Can anyone please help me out?

Comment: Did you recently change the db settings in your `.env` file? Then maybe the old settings are still cached for web requests. You could try clearing the cache and/or restarting your webserver just to be sure.

Comment: Yeah, i tried that but sadly that didn't do the trick for me.

Answer (score 0):

sometimes `.env` archive not reload for change... maybe you need run command `php artisan config:cache`

Answer (score 0):

This is my settings in the .env for the database:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=homestead
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=
```

And this are the ones from database.php:

```
'mysql' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'homestead'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'root'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
        'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'strict' => true,
        'engine' => null,
],
```

But as i understand it both the migrations, seeds and the api goes thru .env.